# Digital certificate authentication of user in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Do we need to modify document send API by passing parameters or some other way so that DocuSign understand that receiver uses digital signature to sign the document?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update your Envelopes: create call if you want one or more signer recipients to use digital signatures.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536575/64904